# histogram of gray scale values in numpy image

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, matplotlib

I loaded an image into a numpy array and want to plot its color values in a histogram.

```
import numpy as np

from skimage import io
from skimage import color

img = io.imread('img.jpg')
img = color.rgb2gray(img)

unq = np.unique(img)
unq = np.sort(unq)
```

When we inspect the value of `unq` we will see something like

```
array([  5.65490196e-04,   8.33333333e-04,   1.13098039e-03, ...,
         7.07550980e-01,   7.09225490e-01,   7.10073725e-01])
```

which has still too much values for `matplotlib` so my idea was to loop over `unq` and remove every value which deviates only `x` from it's predecessor.

```
dels = []

for i in range(1, len(unq)):
    if abs(unq[i]-unq[i-1]) < 0.0003:
        dels.append(i)

unq = np.delete(unq, dels)
```

Though this method works it is very inefficient as it does not uses numpy's optimized implementations.

**Is there a numpy feature would could do this for me?**

*Just noticed that my algorithm looses information about how often a color occurs. Let me try to fix this*.

Comment: Why not use [`np.histogram(img, bins)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) (or [`plt.hist(img.ravel(), bins)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) if you just want to plot it)?

Comment: @ali_m yes this would answer my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want to compute the histogram, you can use [`np.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
bin_counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(img, bins, ...)
```

Here, `bins` could either be the number of bins, or a vector specifying the upper and lower bin edges.

If you want to plot the histogram, the easiest way would be to use [`plt.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist):

```
bin_counts, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(img.ravel(), bins, ...)
```

Note that I used `img.ravel()` to flatten out the image array before computing the histogram. If you pass a 2D array to `plt.hist()`, it will treat each row as a separate data series, which is not what you want here.

Comment: Thank you for the great tipp with `plt.hist(img.ravel())`! How can I read the gray value from the histogram (scale only goes from 0 to 0.8)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The x-axis represents gray values, and the y-axis represents frequency. If the x scale runs from 0 to 0.8 then all of your gray values lie between 0 and 0.8, which looks consistent with the values you show in `unq`.